# An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the PutObject operation

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-templates, bucket

I'm trying to upload the images of my django project to s3 bucket. I have the following in my settings

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'my_key_id'

AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'my_secret_key'

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'app_name'

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False

i have this in my aws permisions

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1665038511106",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1665038504281",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::novacreditbank/*"
    }
]
```

}

I keep getting this error

```
NoSuchBucket at /admin/Novaapp/data/1/change/
```

An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the PutObject operation: The specified bucket does not exist

Comment: You appear to be attempt to access the bucket called `app_name`, but giving permissions for the bucket `novacreditbank`.  Which is the bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, it appears your permission is for getObject, but will need another policy statement for PutObject.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).